# Core Plot CPTBorderedLayer not animating

Tags: calayer, core-plot, cabasicanimation

I have a `CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation` whose `contentLayer` property is a `CPTBorderedLayer` object. I'm trying to animate the `CPTBorderedLayer` object with the following:

```xcode
CGRect originalBounds = annotation.contentLayer.bounds;
CGRect expandedBounds = annotation.contentLayer.bounds;
expandedBounds.size.width *= 1.5f;
expandedBounds.size.height *= 1.5f;

CABasicAnimation* boundsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
boundsAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
boundsAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:originalBounds];
boundsAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:expandedBounds];
boundsAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
boundsAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[annotation.contentLayer addAnimation:boundsAnimation forKey:@"bounds"];
```

But this isn't animating. Setting the `bounds` directly to `expandedBounds` works, but it won't animate. Thoughts?

Comment: I dropped this code into one of the Core Plot example apps and it worked as expected. The problem is somewhere else in your app.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out last night. It seems that using setting `collapsesLayers` to `YES` on my graph was the problem. Just one of those days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had the `collapsesLayers` property on my `CPTGraphHostingView` set to `YES`. Setting it to `NO` fixed the issue.